# Safari failing to send valid GET request using Angular's HttpClient

Tags: ios, angular, http, safari, intermittent

When sending a GET request in Safari, Safari is failing to send a valid request to the server. In fact, it isn't even reaching the server (I've checked this on the back end). Its also failing to provide all but two of the request headers and the response is null (which results in safari logging a kcferrordomaincfnetwork error 303 in the console). I've attached some screenshots below along with some additional findings. Can anyone provide any insight?

- [Screenshot of the request when it fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bWWV.png)
- [Screenshot of the request when it passes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocbhg.jpg)
- Issue is only reproducible in Safari on iOS devices.
- Issue was happening on the MacBook previously. After clearing the website data once, we never saw the issue again
- The call is intermittently failing
- When setting a breakpoint before the product details call and manually calling it in the console, it fails the first time and then passes the second time.
- Sometimes it isn’t the product details call that is failing (although it usually is)
- Sometimes it is the create app or get product image call that fails.
- Issue seems to go away after clearing website data, but comes back after one successful session.
- When the call fails, we are getting the following error in the console: kcferrordomaincfnetwork error 303
- Session storage is empty and issue persists
- No exceptions are occurring (I enabled "break on all exceptions" in Safari)

Comment: Have you resolved this? I have shared component and it works on one page and not on the other and only on iOS device

Answer (score 0):

Try running **ng serve** with the **--no-live-reload** option.  We were seeing similar behavior, and WDS may have been interrupting the HTTP calls.  So far, this has solved our problem.